# Add a new column in table using Laravel 10, showing error Exception Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

Laravel 10 showing error Exception Illuminate\Database\QueryException

I am using Laravel 10 and I am trying to add a new column in the table students, using these below steps in the terminal.

- Step 1: php artisan make:migration update_student_table --table=students
- Step 2: in the 2023_08_17_055949_update_student_table.php file add the code

https://prnt.sc/fdGTj1t_3iIJ

- Step 3: php artisan migrate run this command
- Step 4: in the terminal, it is showing the Error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAnWh.png)

I am trying to add a new column in the table, but showing the below error
exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yFeU.png)

Comment: According to your error. it is clear that you are running migration but students table is recreating. that's why you should delete students table from db manually and also delete create students table migration from migrations table manually. 

or you can try rollback by one step and fix the issue , then again do migration

Comment: If you delete file with that new migration and run `php artisan migrate` do you still have an error?

Comment: You can add, as first line of `up` method in `2023_08_17_053215_create_students_table.php` file, `if (Schema::hasTable('students')) { return; }`.

Comment: the error is in your `create_students_table` migration, not `update_students_table`. please provide your first migration

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use below code

```
Schema::table('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('city', 30)->after('id'); // change after column
});
```

Comment: what does this have to do with the error?

Comment: Thank yo so much its working you are great..................

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your 2nd image, when you ran

```
php artisan migrate
```

Then create_students_table migration ran first as the students' table already exists which throws an exception.

This happens if somehow create_student_table didn't ran before or entry is deleted from migrations table of your database.

Alternatively for specific migration you can try.

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/your_table.
```

Comment: This answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the `update_student_table` but rather your migration is trying to re-create the `students` table in the `create_student_table` migration file.

Now I do not know how you structure your application.

The `students` table was probably created on a different branch with a different migration file, created manually inside your SQL GUI or any other reasons.

If you do not mind to **RECREATE/DELETE** your entire tables, you can do:

`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

Else, **fix** the migration setup. ( check other migration files if `students` table was already created )

Below is the sample error on my app where you can see it said `users` table already exist.

[image: My error of users table already created]

Inside `create_password_resets_table` trying to create the `users` table again

[image: inside create_password_resets_table trying to create the users table again]